# jquery DDoS prevention

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, ddos

I'm using this example in my Codeigniter project and want to know how I can prevent people using code below for DDoS style attacks? Do I change code below or should I do something in my Codeigniter controller?

Also one more thing, which approach is better?

**VERSION 1:**

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
$.post('ci_class/ci_method', form_data, function(response)
```

**VERSION 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#img_search").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        var p    = $('#text_postcode').attr('value');
        var hash = $('#hidden_hash').attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url     : 'ci_class/ci_method',
            data        : 'pc=' + pc + '&hash=' + hash,
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(response)
            {
```

Comment: I wouldn't call busy clicking a "Denial of Service attack", much less a "Distributed Denial of Service attack". If people want to DoS you, they don't need a bug on your side, just a little programming skill.

Comment: do you know what mean ddos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything in the client code to prevent DDoS attacks, because attacks like that won't use the client code anyway.

Regarding which approach is better, it depends on what you think is better.

The first approach is simpler and adapts dynamically to any fields that you put in the form.

The second approach is more precise, and only sends exactly the data that is needed to the server, but the drawback is that you have to update the code when you add another field that you want to send to the server.

---

Tip: You can use the `val` method instead of `attr('value')`:

```
var p = $('#text_postcode').val();
var hash = $('#hidden_hash').val();
```

You can put the values in an object literal instead of concatenating strings to form the data:

```
data: { pc: pc, hash: hash },
```

Comment: Yes object literal and `val()` style looks better. I'll use them. Thanks